# Is all use of illegal drugs abuse?

Tags: word-usage

"abuse" is often defined as improper usage.

When speaking about an illegal drug, it seems impossible to properly use it (I mean here recreational consumption, not specially licensed medical or research use). So then, is any consumption automatically abuse?

**EDIT:** I see that somehow, several users appear to have misinterpreted my question. I would like to clarify:

Even substances which are illegal may be used legally by people such as medical doctors and scientists, by special permit. Obviously this is not abuse. It falls within the special exemptions provided by the law. I am asking about using the word "*abuse*" to describe use of these drugs ***outside such special permits, when the law considers the use clearly illegal***.

Comment: *abuse*: **1** Use (something) to bad effect or for a **bad purpose**; misuse; **1.1** Make **excessive and habitual use** of (alcohol or drugs, especially illegal ones) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abuse?q=abuse

Comment: Use for medical purposes under medical supervision is not considered *abuse*, possibly the sole exception.

Comment: "Abuse" and "illegal use" are different concepts.  If someone has a legal prescription of pain drugs but uses them off-prescription, that's abuse.  If someone uses cocaine recreationally but never becomes an addict, I'd say they are using illegal drugs but not abusing them.  I guess the question is, how would you define ***"abuse"***, right?  The other factor is, what is the motivation of the user of the word "abuse"?  IMO, the word "abuse" is abused to serve an agenda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abuse in the pharmaceutical sense means use improperly.  [Source DEA Drugs of Abuse](http://www.justice.gov/dea/docs/drugs_of_abuse_2011.pdf)

The use of illegal drugs is abuse by this definition.  The reason being that there is no intended proper use for those drugs.

Take the case of heroin.  Heroin (diacetylmorphine) has no therapeutic use that is recognized by the DEA.  Its only recognized use (by US law) is to get high. Hence, its use is always considered to be abuse.  (*Note* it is rarely used for extreme pain management in the UK and some other countries, but its use is highly regulated.)

Marijuana and cocaine, by contrast have recognized therapeutic uses.  Marijuana can be used for intractable nausea, glaucoma, extreme cases of anorexia, and other recognized uses.  Cocaine is a both a local anesthetic and vasoconstriction agent which is used in ENT and ophthalmologic surgeries.  When used in the properly prescribed conditions, the use of these agents is *not* abuse.  But, when used for non-prescription uses (recreational, etc.) it constitutes abuse.

People frequently mistake abuse for addiction.  That is a separate concept.  Addiction is the excessive habitual use, and implies a psychosocial dependency on the drug that outstrips its usefulness therapeutically.  Contrast this with dependance, which represents a physical need for a drug without the underlying psychosocial components or excesses.

*Source:  I am a physician who practices Anesthesiology.  I hold a DEA license to prescribe controlled substances.  And, I have training in the administration of controlled substances, and diversion prevention.*

Comment: Hang on, mate. Heroin is an opiate which is very similar to oxycodone... that is used very normally as a painkiller. Heroin could easily substitute for this.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Note that I said by the DEA or most medical authorities.  Yes, it was originally used for pain management purposes, but it was banned by the DEA (Schedule 1).  It is rarely used in the UK and some other countries, but typically only in extreme cases.  It is similar to oxycodone in structure, but FAR more addictive.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Clarified the point in my post.

Comment: @DavidM - your answer is flawed.  First of all which government are we looking too to tell whether a drug has been abused?  So someone smoking pot in US is abuse but in Denmark it isn't?  Also what happens when states in the US allow certain drug activity?  Using the same drug is no longer abuse?  Also what is improper?  There are guys I work with that smoke a pack of cigarettes a day but that isn't abuse?  I don't think the word "abuse" conveys any authoritative symbolism so bringing government function is mute to me.

Comment: @RyeBread Your reasoning is flawed.  Abuse is the improper use (improper for a variety of reasons).  If something is legal (*e.g.* alcohol) then abuse constitutes the excessive legal use to the point of damage.  If it is illegal, there is by definition, no proper use, hence it always abuse.  Read the link to the DEA I posted above.  It explains the definition on page 8.

Comment: @DavidM - so we should rely on the DEA as the new dictionary?  I understand your logic.  What I don't agree with is the usage of the word outside of internal meetings by the DEA or medical profession.  I still don't understand how you would explain how I am not abusing pot in Colorado and can physically step one foot outside state lines and now be abusing pot.  No where did the OP ask for DEA or medical usage.

Comment: @Ryebread He did. He said *illegal* drugs. Who do you assume decided it was an *illegal* drug?  (It wasn't my Aunt, that's for sure!)  As I keep repeating, you keep assuming that abuse has only one definition.  It's just not true.  The DEA (and some state legislatures) define a drug as legal or illegal. Once you use a drug in a manner that isn't intended medically you are abusing it.  Let me give you a counter point. If I hit a child one time with my fist, did I abuse them?  Or is it not abuse until there is a pattern?

Comment: @DavidM - that analogy doesn't work because hitting a child with a fist isn't acceptable in some areas and not others.  But to answer the analogy - one time no.  It would be assault though.  A pattern would make it abuse to me.

Comment: @RyeBread Like it or not, it meets the definition of abuse when you use a drug other than its intended purpose. You and others keep confusing abuse with addiction or problematic usage.  While these represent forms of abuse, they are not the exclusive forms.  You are not only arguing with me, but also the DEA, and most dictionaries. [Read the second definition under substance abuse](http://i.word.com/idictionary/abuse). As you've pointed out repeatedly, legality matters. And, it determines at what point does usage constitute abuse.

Comment: So if US outlaws chocolate you would say your mom is abusing chocolate when she has a candy bar?  And again I am not saying what the judge would say.  I am talking every day usage of the word.  Please tell me your mom wouldn't be abusing chocolate?

Comment: @RyeBread it would only be abuse if it was outlawed by dint of its pharmaceutical nature. I don't say that people abuse illegal weapons. I say that they use them illegally. I don't say that people abuse Cuban cigars. That is the importation of contraband. Etc.  We're speaking of a narrow usage here that has a specific definition.

Comment: @DavidM - that is why I used chocolate in my example.  One of the most commonly used drugs in the world.  I get that abuse is used formally but I don't hear it used.

Comment: @RyeBread Chocolate is not a drug. It is classified as a food by the FDA. (You could argue its medicinal properties make it a medication or supplement, but it's not classified as such).  It is perfectly legal in all jurisdictions that I know of.  And, yes someone could abuse chocolate in the broader sense. Just as they could abuse alcohol.  If you were a diabetic with elevated blood sugar. You could make an argument that the use of chocolate was, abuse. I doubt most would say that, but they could.

Comment: @DavidM - Chocolate isn't a drug?  I think the world would disagree with you - http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2206310/Chocolate-create-high-opium-Links-obese-people-drug-addicts.html.  Also how about caffeinated soda?  Why would an English word's premise be determined by the FDA or DEA which are just in the US?

Comment: @ryebread This is an example of a little knowledge is a dangerous thing. Running has similar effects on the brains of runners. Is running now a drug?  The article is speaking about the changes in brain chemistry, not the definition as a drug.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, not all illegal drugs are *"abused"*, and *"abuse"* does not necessarily mean the drug is illegal. It's easier explaining the difference with "legal" drugs, such as doctor-prescribed pain-killers:

> Bob started using pain killers after his injury.
>   Bob started abusing pain killers after his injury.

The former sentence means Bob is using the drugs properly; the latter means he is using them improperly, even if those drugs technically are legal.

As a side note, one could probably argue that not all illegal drugs are harmful and therefore not "abusive" (but that's not a discussion fit for this StackExchange), but the types of drugs that are illegal are usually such due to being harmful and have a tendency to become abused.

Similarly, people typically use the word "abuse" with illegal drugs because the word carries a negative connotation. As **tobyink** put it so well in the comments: *"If you choose to always use the word 'abuse' rather than 'use' when talking about illegal drugs, this probably implies that you are of the opinion that all illegal drug use is improper, and therefore abusive."*

Comment: But how can a drug be *used properly* if it is illegal to use at all? Doesn't illegal use imply improper use?

Comment: @Superbest Legal status shouldn't make a difference. For _"abuse"_, perhaps think of it as _used for the wrong purpose_ instead of _used improperly_.

Comment: @Superbest One typically doesn't use the word _"abuse"_ when describing someone having taken a drug once; the word implies regular use and a problem.

Comment: Supporting @IQAndreas, one definition of _abuse_ is _make excessive and habitual use of (alcohol or drugs, esp. illegal ones)_.

Comment: Some people use illegal marijuana for pain only; this would not be abuse. I agree with this guy.

Comment: This is a situation where your choice of word says less about your care of proper English, than it does about your opinions of drug control laws. If you choose to always use the word "abuse" rather than "use" when talking about illegal drugs, this probably implies that you are of the opinion that all illegal drug use is improper, and therefore abusive.

Comment: I am still confused. How can an action which violates the law ever be proper? Can the "right purpose" of a thing be something illegal?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I had already excluded that case from my question.

Comment: @IQAndreas Abuse means using the drug in a manner other than the intended purpose.  It has nothing to do with habitual or excessive use.  That is addiction.

Comment: @DavidM I got that definition from the Oxford American Dictionary.

Comment: @Superbest You're assuming laws always reflect what's right. Did drinking alcohol become wrong when Prohibition was passed, then become right when it was repealed? Or was it just a law that did not match reality? Was slavery correct until the Emancipation Proclamation?

Comment: @Barmar The OED is often behind on medical terminology.  Abuse has a clear definition in medical terms.  It is improper use.  And, there are drugs for which there is *no* proper use.

Comment: Are we talking about the way the term is used in the medical profession, or how it's used in common parlance?

Comment: @Barmar The definition is contained with the question itself.  *Illegal drugs* cannot be used properly by definition.  There is no *proper* use for an illegal drug.  If there is a *proper* use, it is no longer *illegal*.

Comment: @Barmar Well, yes. It became illegal. As a rule, illegal=wrong is a fairly robust heuristic. You may contend that just because something is illegal doesn't mean it's necessarily wrong - but then I challenge you to provide a better definition of "proper use" in the context of drugs, and to show how this definition is more naturally assumed by English speakers.

Comment: Alcohol is still illegal in some Muslim-majority countries. Therefore, use of alcohol is improper and thus abuse. Valid reasoning?

Answer (score -1):

If you smoked a joint a few times a year at parties, I would say you enjoyed your pot usage.  I doubt anyone would describe that as drug abuse.  Even when using "harsher" drugs it would be about context.  Abuse seems to insinuate some form of mid to long term usage.

Comment: That was abuse of the drug.  Not serious, hardcore, or even addictive behavior, but still abuse.

Comment: @DavidM - you can think that but would someone use that word to describe it (other than you and the other 2%)... no.

Comment: Not to pull rank.  I'm a Doctor, possess a DEA license, and know the actual definition on this one.  Sorry.  It's abuse.  It's not addiction, but it's still abuse.

Comment: @DavidM - it doesn't matter what the medical definition is.  It matters what the word conveys to the audience.  If you said that someone "abused" pot and they had one puff at a party, almost anyone would be thoroughly confused.

Comment: How many puffs does it take then?  17?  438?  What is the *official* crowd-sourced definition?

Comment: @DavidM - I might test this out tonight.  Wait is testing abuse?

Comment: "*I doubt anyone would describe that as drug abuse*" - I can imagine many such individuals; for instance a federal judge or a state prosecutor. Is there a source for "insinuate long term usage"?

Comment: We aren't here to debate the use of drugs, just to discuss the language.  "Abuse" means improper use.  What that means, exactly, is up to whoever is using the word, but generally it means "illegal use."

Comment: @BenMiller - So you would be fine with the following sentence then - "I thought my friend was abusing marijuana, but it turns out she was in Colorado last night."

Comment: @RyeBread That depends: The state of Colorado would be fine with it, but the federal government would not.

Comment: @BenMiller - You just proved my point.  It is either something or it isn't.  People do not think the word abuse is tied to governmental whims.

Comment: @RyeBread No, my point is that someone from the state government of Colorado would not call it abuse, because they would see it as proper use, and someone from the federal government would call it abuse, because to them it is improper use.  Either way, legality is tied to the definition.  Abuse means "improper use," and whoever is using the word decides what that means.

Comment: @BenMiller - That is one of many meanings of the word abuse.  I don't think the question hinted at the person using the word abuse was a judge or in the federal government.  Therefor I would assume they want the general use of the word.  And I cannot name anyone that would roll it up as a catch-all for anything illegal.  The government can make anything illegal and we would all be abusing things daily - sounds really silly to me.

Comment: @RyeBread There is value in what you are saying. But, that value stands in the colloquial usage. Unfortunately, this line of thinking is what leads to people developing serious drug habits. I was trying to resist this line of argument because it's weak sauce. But, I feel you need to understand why this is dangerous. Just one pill becomes just a few more, it's not abuse, right?  So when is it an use?  Once addiction sets in?  The first time you drive high?  If you wish to make a statement, give a parameter other than "I know it when I see it …".

Comment: Ran out of char. The question about when does abuse set in with legal drugs is a fascinating psycho-social question. I agree with you that it is extremely hard to define that point. Hence, it is hard to recognize and treat addiction until it has severe ramifications.  I'd love to discuss this further in chat some time.